# How to concatenate two DataFrame by repeating a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a two DataFrame and I need repeat Cars as many times as questions and export it to .csv
DataFrame_1:

```
Opinion    
 Cars   
 Cars
 Cars
 Cars
 Cars
 Cars
 Cars
 Cars
```

And DataFrame_2

```
  Questions
   Like Cars
   Model
   Years
   color
```

Final DataFrame

```
  Opinion   Questions
    Cars      Like Cars
    Cars      Model
    Cars      Years
    Cars      Color
```

Any panda function that allows this to be done?

Comment: IIUIC, Why not just do `df2.assign(Opinion='Cars')` or `df2['Opinion'] = 'Cars'`?

Comment: Yes, this works if only I had the opinion "Cars", but in reality I have a file that has many opinions with your questions.

My idea is to extract opinions and questions automatically.

Comment: I think the question needs to be formulated better, including a Minimal, complete and verfiable example

Comment: From DataFrame 1 How do I select "Cars" in a variable to assign it to DataFrame 2?

Comment: your ask is unclear, please post a better sample data for better understanding, the question which you have posted is actually answered by @Yuca .

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DataFrame_2['Opinion'] = 'Cars'
```